# Using regex quantifier with find

Tags: find, regular-expression

I've got a set of files in a directory, all of the format `test[0-9][0-9].txt`. If I run

```
find . -regex ".*/(test)[0-9][0-9]\.txt"
```

then all the files are shown, but if I run

```
find . -regex ".*/(test)[0-9]{2}\.txt"
```

then none are shown. What am I doing wrong?!

I've had a search through previous similar questions to this, but can't find a particularly relevant answer

Comment: The first example uses normal regexp syntax, where the second uses extended syntax. Your version of `find` obviously expects the former by default. You don't say what system you're on - your `find` might have a switch to turn on extended regexp parsing. On FreeBSD, for example, it's `-E`

Comment: @D_Bye ah, that's a good point. CentOS6. I've tried `-regextype posix-extended` and that doesn't work either

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using `GNU` find, this should work for you

```
 find . -regextype sed -regex "./test[0-9]\{2\}.txt"
```

#### Explanation

- `-regextype sed` - use basic posix regular expression (just because thats what Im familiar with)
- `./` - necessary because find considers all file paths on a relative search to begin with this pattern
- `[0-9]\{2\}` - 2 instances of the `[0-9]` digit character class with the quantifier `\{...\}` brackets escaped - per [basic posix regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html)